# Draw the closed ball centered at $(0,0)$ of radius $3$ in $\mathbb R^2$

Tags: general-topology

This is my question

> Draw the closed ball centered at $(0,0)$ of radius $3$ in $\mathbb R^2$.

I understand the definition of a closed ball and I'm supposed to be drawing it in the $2$ dimensional space. I basically drew a circle centered at $(0,0)$ with radius $3$ and it is marked wrong on my homework. I asked my professor but she wanted me to rework this problem on my own so she said that she can't just give me the answer. (She could have helped though.) I did draw the boundary as included.

This is what I drew. I did draw the boundary as included. Can someone show me the correct way to draw a closed ball in $\mathbb R^2$?
[image]

Comment: Have you marked the inside as well? Plus indicate that the boundary is part of the set as well.

Comment: What topology were you asked to use?

Comment: Let me ask you a question: Do you think  the *circle* is the closed ball? Tell me in words (you can give specific points as examples) what the closed ball is.    Which of these points does  it include: (3,3), ($\sqrt{4.5},\sqrt{4.5}$), (2,2),  (1,1), (0,0)$?

Comment: I know that the closed ball is more like a sphere. But since this is 2 dimensions it looks more like a circle. Because it extends with a radius of 3, I just assumed that the only way to represent that was a circle.

Comment: Melanie-- You should have shaded the inside also to get it right. (See answer below.)

Comment: That wasn't the point of my question.  A closed ball is *not* more like a sphere (which is three dimensions) than a circle (both the circle and the closed ball are two dimensions and *can* be drawn on you two dimensional paper. My question is: tell me in words what you think a closed ball is and tell my in words what you think a circle is.  Do you think they are the same thing.  What points (if any) do they have in common.  What points (if any) does one have that the other doesn't?  Hint: they are different.

Comment: "I understand the definition of a closed ball"  I thought at first you did, but seeing you answers and you drawing I don't think you do.  A closed ball is not a circle.  I think once you reread the definition of a closed ball and reread the definition of a circle you will understand the difference.  (Def: circle:  all points that are a certain distance from a center point.  Def: closed ball: all points within a certain distance from a center point.  Def: open ball: all points less than a distance from a center point.  Do you see the three differences?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term "ball" refers to all points at distance less or equal $r$ from a center $(a,b).$ So it includes the points inside the bounding circle, as well as the circle itself. One way this is drawn is by shading the inside and making the bounding circle as a solid rather than dashed curve. (A dashed curve would go with an open ball, whereas your example is of a closed ball.)

Comment: Oops, basically just duped your answer.

Comment: @BrianTung I've done that lots of times, where while I was typing an answer another had come in before I posted. No prob...